# 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Error

Tags: python

I am writing a function to help out our test department put random phone numbers into a phone number field.

Here is my code:

```
from random import randrange

def phonenumbergenerator():
    phonenumber = randrange(1111111111, 9999999999)
    phonenumberformatted = (str("%s-%s-%s" % (phonenumber[:3], phonenumber[3:6], phonenumber[6:])))
    return phonenumberformatted

print phonenumbergenerator()
```

I am getting the following error when I try to run this and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly here:

`TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `phonenumber` is an `int`, not yet a `str`. `__getitem__` is the `[:3]` notation. Easiest solution:

```
from random import randrange

def phonenumbergenerator():
    phonenumber = str(randrange(1111111111, 9999999999)) # <-- make it a string
    phonenumberformatted = (str("%s-%s-%s" % (phonenumber[:3], phonenumber[3:6], phonenumber[6:])))
    return phonenumberformatted
```

Gave me:

```
>>> phonenumbergenerator()
415-867-5309
```

---

A good way to troubleshoot exceptions like this is to split the work onto multiple lines, so you have a better idea of where the exception occurred. For instance:

```
area_code = phonenumber[:3]
prefix    = phonenumber[3:6]
suffix    = phonenumber[6:]
phonenumberformatted = (str("%s-%s-%s" % (area_code, prefix, suffix)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a number, `phonenumber`, as if it was a string. Try with:

```
phonestr = str(phonenumber)
phonestr[:3], ...
```